# I can't sign in to my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support

I created an account here and used my work e-mail. Stack Overflow kept me signed in so I never had to enter my password.

Is there any way to keep my old account and reputation?

Do I make a new account with the same name and my same picture?

Do I just make a brand new account with some fake name to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 4):

Do you still have access to that email address?

If so, two things you can do:

1. Go through [account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery); or
2. Visit the [contact page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and request this new account you're posting from to be merged with your original one.

If you don't have access to your work email, use the [contact page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and submit an "Other" request explaining the situation. Our support team will see what can be done in that case.

Comment: It was a work e-mail and I do not work there anymore so, no, I do not have access to the e-mail anymore.  I sent a request to the contact page.  thanks.